# can autocorrelation in the residuals impact my predictions?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, forecasting, autocorrelation

I'm building a linear regression model to forecast the price of nitrogen fertilzers. My predictors are grain prices (wheat, corn or soybeans) and natural gas prices. When I look at autocorrelation of residuals, I get 0.9 which implies that there may be positive autocorrelation. Will this make my predictions of fertilizer prices biased? When can we ignore autocorrelation problem if we can at all?
How can I improve it?

Comment: If your goal is prediction then you can ignore it. As long as you have tested your model and it forecasts well, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @user2974951, if the goal is prediction, I would definitely pay attention to autocorrelation in the residuals and try to exploit it. Strongly autocorrelated residuals suggest you can predict what forecast error you will make. Ignoring that means a missed opportunity for obtaining a more accurate forecast. This is equivalent to using a constant-only model where an ARMA model is appropriate.

Comment: What do you mean by "pay attention to autocorrelation in the residuals and try to exploit it". How can I do it?